Retrieve ACC Project used template
Is there a way to retrieve the Project template used to create a Project? I've highlighted in the image where this sits in the UI.
I've tried using the Account API ( https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/admin-projectsprojectId-GET/ ) and the Data API ( https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-hub_id-projects-project_id-GET/ )
but it is not visible in any of those two APIs.
Thanks,
Pablo.

I doubt there is an Autodesk API that retrieves the project template used to create a particular project. Atleast I am not aware of any.
I know this info you can get from the UI but kindly allow me to consult on this with larger team and get back to you.

Hi, there is no provision of this info in any of APS APIs currently. A ticket has been logged under: "AECP-1145:Wish: Request to have an API to determine the template Id where an existing project is created from" to be implemented. I will update on the progress of this wish.
